# How can I assign different iteration within for loop in C#?

Tags: c#, image, list

I have list called “images” which is contained of the series of bitmap images.

My question is how can I loop through every single element of my “images” list and do this operation for different elements of my list “images”?

Comment: Like `foreach (var image in images)`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. StackOverflow is not a site where we will do your job. You have [posted many questions today related to this simple task](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3384676/user3384676). Please put some effort to answer yourself such trivial task. Return here when you reach a real blocking situation. If you are a beginner, it's ok, but please learn the language.

Comment: I dont understand what you're trying to do.  Try rewording your question.

Comment: On a sidenote, the code above looks very imperformant. Storing pixels in a dynamic list may not be wise. Also that you store 0/1 in it you are better off using smaller datatypes than an integer.
Storing 0 / 1 each on a separate line in the file lets me wonder about the use case.

Comment: That said, all of your questions make me think that you have a greater goal than just what is described here. Please beware of not falling in the [XY problem trap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to keep collections for each element of `images`, right?

You'll need to maintain a list of lists, or something similar:

```
List<List<int>> stuffOfImages = new List<List<int>>();
for (int x = 0; x < images[i].Width; x++)  {
  var stuffOfImage = new List<int>();
  stuffOfImages.Add(stuffOfImage);
  for (int y = 0; y < images[i].Height; y++) {

  }
}
```

Note that you lose all reference to the associated image - it might be worthy creating a type so you can keep a reference to the image and the integer collection associated with it in one place and related.

I'm a little unclear as to what you mean, so please elaborate if necessary.